# How to fill DataGridCell with color depends on value it contains WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

Hello,

at the beginning I want to mention that is my first post so I'm asking for understanding.

I have a data grid (WPF) and I want to fill its cells with color depend on value that cell contains. I'm filling my datagrid (either columns and rows) dynamically by setting items source like that

```
myDataGrid.ItemsSource = myDataTable.DefaultView;
```

so I cannot set columns style in xaml before setting items source.

I tried several ways, such:
 
1.) To get single cell and set its background property such [>>this<<](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125502/how-to-get-a-cell-from-datagrid),
but `presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex()`
 
always returns null (I have no idea how to fix that)

2.) To create a xaml cell style and converter such this

VIEW

```
<DataGrid CellStyle="{StaticResource MyDataGridCell}"/>
```

STYLE

```
  <Style x:Key="MyDataGridCell" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource CellColorConverter}"/>
    </Style>
```

CONVERTER

```
public class CellColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is DataGridCell)
            {
                string text = (value as DataGridCell).Content.ToString();

                int input = string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) ? 0 : System.Convert.ToInt32(text);


                if (input >= 0)
                {
                    return Brushes.Green;
                }
                if (input < 0)
                {
                    return Brushes.Red;
                }
            }
            return Brushes.Gray;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

But `value.Content` is always null and I don't know how to pass DataGridCell text to a converter.

At the end grid should look like [that](https://ibb.co/e56sAA)

Comment: I found that before but it is not a solution for my problem. Main reason is that if I set 
<DataGridTextColumn>
then 
myDataGrid.ItemsSource = myDataTable.DefaultView; 
is throwing an exception because myDataGrid is not empty.

Comment: Have you looked at the second answer for that question? It seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: Ehh.. I spent so long to find a solution and it was closer than i thought. Don't know how i could miss that answer. Thank you very much, that is exacly what i was looking for!